# Map multiple objects in to action class in struts2

Tags: struts2

I  have jsp page with multiple item objects. and gives action to Shop_shopCart.action.
inside action class there are cart object with multiple item objects. How it is possible to directly mapping from jsp to action class with multiple list objects.
Demo classes are given below.

```
<s:form action="Shop_shopCart.action">
    // multiple items in cart object
</form>

class ShoppingAction extends ActionSupport{
Cart cart = new Cart();
//getters and setters
//action methods
        String shopCart( ) {
                // do some         
        }
}


class Cart{
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();  
//getters and setters
}

class Item{
String name;
int id;
//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [type conversion collection and map support docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-CollectionandMapSupport).

Nutshell: array or map notation (square brackets with an index or key value inside them) is the easiest way to submit a collection of objects in a form.

Answer (score -1):

this example should help

```
 <s:form action="saveaction" theme="css_xhtml">
            <s:textfield name="carlist[0].cartid" label="Cart Id"/>
            <s:textfield name="carlist[0].items[0].id" label="Item id"/>
            <s:textfield name="carlist[0].items[0].name" label="Item Name"/>

            <s:textfield name="carlist[1].cartid" label="Cart Id"/>
            <s:textfield name="carlist[1].items[0].id" label="Item id"/>
            <s:textfield name="carlist[1].items[0].name" label="Item Name"/>
            <s:submit value="Click me to submit Cart List"/>
        </s:form>
```